# Automatically create .aspx file on my web hositing files

Tags: c#, asp.net

hi everyone from few days in my web hosting files , file name `skin.aspx` is automatically created on every root directory.

[Click here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u0ura1f80hgl4hh/skin.txt?dl=0) the attach code of the `skin.aspx` file.

need your help and expertise  and how to prevent from this.

Comment: is your project Web Application Projects (WAP) or Web Site Projects (WSP). ?

Comment: @user1089766  Web Site Projects (WSP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ASPX file keeps appearing automatically even after you delete it and it really is web hosting service, not your own server, you really need to contact your web hosting company's support as it is the design of their system and not a programming question.

Also, as it appears, DotNetNuke CMS is probably the cause of the file appearing, [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/625320.aspx?) describes the import process that creates the ASPX file. If your website runs on DotNetNuke and it is indeed a web hosting as opposed to VPS or your own server, I am affraid you are out of luck when it comes to getting rid of this file.

Comment: Actually we have the dedicated server and host the site from iis8 from own

Comment: And do you use DotNetNuke? If so, I'm sure this kind of thing is configurable. But I have never worked with DotNetNuke, so I don't know how you could disable it. I'm affraid the only thing I can advise is to look through the configuration and try to sport something related to skining or download [FileMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) utility and figure out what process creates the file and disable it.